# How to fix "failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10083: Read-only file system" error?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I got this error:

```
failed to make and  /acct/ui d _ 10083: Read-only file system
```

When I run my app I got "unfortunately app has stopped". How do I clear this? I am using progress bar then only I got this problem.

Comment: Improve header and body text

Comment: this happen in my ubuntu 16.04 too